# Php print online usernames from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, list

I'm trying to add a online and offline user list to my webpage. Im running a type of game server. I have a column in the database auth, in table accounts.

I want to have a heading of online: then a list of online users
then heading of offline: then offline users

I would also like to show the number of online and offline accounts.

Im pretty poor at this but i've managed to do it for one user account but instead of it just checking if one user is online i want it to check everyone. 
the way i've done it i would manually have to repeat this code for each account in the database. 
Here is what ive got:

```
$DBTYPE = 'mysql';
$DBHOST = '127.0.0.1';
$DBUSER = 'root';
$DBPASSWORD = 'password';
$DBNAME = 'auth';


$link = mysql_connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD);
mysql_select_db($DBNAME);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$member_id= '1'; // get value of the member, assumed that you have post the data into id. change if it is different into your code

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account where id=$member_id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     if($row['online'] == '1')
     {
        $usernameon = ($row['username']);
     }
     else
     {
        $usernameoff = ($row['username']);
     }
}

$onlineppl="<FONT COLOR=green>[*]Online players:</b></FONT><br />";
echo $onlineppl;
echo $usernameon;
?>
<br />
<br />
<?php
$offlineppl="<FONT COLOR=red>[*]Offline players:</b></FONT><br />";
echo $offlineppl;
if($usernameoff == '');
$usernameoff="We're all online";
echo $usernameoff;
```

I know there's definitely a better, cleaner way of doing this but i just dont know it yet? any suggestions?? :)
Im pretty sure the if command is wrong as well but im hoping someone can solve that as well :)

Comment: [FAQ:  What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) - This is a very open-ended question, without a definite answer, exactly like the FAQ says not to ask.

Comment: @user2266565 focus on what would be that better and cleaner way of doing it and then formulate an specific question about it

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$sql = "SELECT username, online FROM ..."
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$users = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $users[$row['online']][] = $row['username'];
}

$online = count($users[1]);
$offline = count($users[0]); // or whatever value you assign to offline users

$online_list = implode(',' $users[1]);
$offline_list = implode(',', $users[0]);
```

points to note:

1) don't do a `select *` when you only need a few of the fields in the table. select * forces the DB to fetch the entire row, and then you throw away almost all of that data.

2) Note the fetch loop innards. It builds an array of offline and online people automatically, removing the need to manually check the online field. Simply build the array, then count its contents afterwards. If you were doing this PURELY to get the online/offline count, then you wouldn't even do this - you'd have the DB do the counting and simply return the results. Never suck data into PHP when you don't have it. It's a waste of CPU time and memory.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: this is not a "please do my work" website. There are load of examples online for things like this.

Anyhow:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account");
$users = array("offline" => array(), "online" => array());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($users))
{
  if ($row['online'] == 1)
    $users['online'][] = $row['username']
  else
    $users['offline'][] = $row['username']
}
```

now $users contains a list of offline users and online users. i you cant manage to get this to work, run some PHP tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$DBTYPE = 'mysql';
$DBHOST = '127.0.0.1';
$DBUSER = 'root';
$DBPASSWORD = 'password';
$DBNAME = 'auth';


$link = mysql_connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD);
mysql_select_db($DBNAME); 
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//$member_id= '1'; // get value of the member, assumed that you have post the data into id. change if it is different into your code

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account);


$totonline=0;
$totoffline=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     if($row['online'] == '1')
     {
        $usernameon .= "<div>".$row['username']."</div>";

        $totonline++;
     }
     else
     {
        $usernameoff .= "<div>".$row['username']."</div>";
        $totoffline++;
     }
}

$onlineppl="<FONT COLOR=green>[*]Online players: Total:".$totonline."</b></FONT><br />";
echo $onlineppl;
echo $usernameon;
?>
<br />
<br />
<?php
$offlineppl="<FONT COLOR=red>[*]Offline players:  Total:".$totoffline."</b></FONT><br />";
echo $offlineppl;
if($usernameoff == '');
$usernameoff="We're all online";
echo $usernameoff;
?>
```